# indexing mysql table using solr error in data-config.xml

Tags: mysql, apache, solr, lucene, jetty

I trying to index my mysql table using apache solr-3.1.0 and the in built Jetty server container  My data-config.xml is

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lol"
user="root"
password="n"/>

<document name="content">
<entity name="id">
query="SELECT id from foo"
 </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

and when i run

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

on the browser i get this error

```
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int 
name="QTime">0</int></lst><lst name="initArgs"><lst name="defaults"><str 
name="config">data-config.xml</str></lst></lst><str name="command">
full-import</str><str name="status">idle</str><str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages"><str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:4.554</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str><str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2013-06-28 11:17:29</str>
<str name="">Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.</str>
<str name="Rolledback">2013-06-28 11:17:29</str></lst>
<str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  
It is likely to change in the future.</str></response>
```

kindly help

and in the query I am selecting id which is of int , is there where i am going wrong 
and here's my .sql file

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.11.1deb1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jun 28, 2013 at 11:41 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.31
-- PHP Version: 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `lol`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `foo`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `koo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ppp` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `foo`
--

INSERT INTO `foo` (`id`, `koo`, `ppp`) VALUES
(1, 'have to do it ', 'lie'),
(2, 'keep quiet', 'kkkk');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

this is parrt of log

```
INFO: SolrUpdateServlet.init() done
2013-06-28 11:17:13.719:WARN::failed SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2013-06-28 11:17:13.719:WARN::failed Server@6d5e3a0c: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2013-06-28 11:17:13.720:WARN::EXCEPTION 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Comment: To me it dosen't look like an error, just details and a WARNING. Do you have any data in your database?

Comment: @vishal.biyani well , i ahve posted my .sql file , an edited the post .. please have a look

Comment: Not enough to understand. Is there any error in Solr logs?

Comment: @vishal.biyani i have posted the log file

Comment: Ok, that's a clear case of port in use. Restart your machine and try again (By restarting all ports will be freed up). Or try chancing the port (Of Solr) to some other port number.

Comment: fine , can i know how to change port no in solr configuaration

Comment: it depends on your container- Tomcat/Jetty whatever you are using. Check the documentation - I would expect you to do that

Comment: @vishal.biyani ok , i use ppp column instead of id here , i get the same error